# Asynchronous call using Spring and Executor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Do we really required to have Executor for @Async in Spring?

What will happen if i am not using Executor interface on the front of thread pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When no custom TaskExecutor is given, or other in other words out-of-box spring uses `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to create threads to handle async.

**SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor** -

- By default concurrent threads is unlimited. Supports control by `concurrencyLimit` property
- No re-use of threads

**TaskExecutor based** -

- Allows to have thread pool with limited number of threads as required
- Since we use thread pools, re-use of threads is done and no overhead.

**Javadoc** : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html